# VBA - Copying and Altering Value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currentlying copying values from one sheet to another sheet using:

```
Worksheets("Source").Range("D2:D" & Last_Index_F).Copy Worksheets("Tabell7").Range("C2")
```

The values I'm copying are numerical values. For each and every value I copy, I want to add 2. It there a way of doing this directly instead of going through the column (using For or While) and adding 2?

Comment: You could read the first range into an array, process (loop) the array (add +2) and then output into the second range.

Comment: Instead of using .Copy use .Value and just throw +2 at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of copying, just assign the `Value` directly...

```
Worksheets("Tabell7").Range("C2").Value =  _ 
    Worksheets("Source").Range("D2:D" & Last_Index_F).Value + 2
```

You will find this is also much quicker, as it avoids writing and retrieving data from the clipboard!